# Trocar primeiro e último elemento de um array criando um novo array

Tags: java, array, elementos

Por que que o valor de `Numbers[0]` muda para 3 após a execução da linha de código abaixo?

```
New_Numbers [0] = Numbers [Numbers.length - 1];
```

O código completo:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

   System.out.print("Indique o número de elementos do array: ");
   int a = scanner.nextInt();
   int [] Numbers = new int [a];
   System.out.println("Indique os três elementos do array:");
   for ( int i = 0; i < a; i++ )
   {
       System.out.print("Número na posição " + i + " do array: ");
       Numbers [i] = scanner.nextInt();
   }
   int [] New_Numbers = Numbers;
   New_Numbers [0] = Numbers [Numbers.length - 1];
   New_Numbers [New_Numbers.length - 1] = Numbers [0];
   String Numbers_S = Arrays.toString(Numbers);
   String New_Numbers_S = Arrays.toString(New_Numbers);
   System.out.println("Array original: " + Numbers_S);
   System.out.println("Novo array após a troca entre o primeiro e o último elementos: " + New_Numbers_S);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Java, quando você atribui um array a outro array, como nessa linha:

```
int [] New_Numbers = Numbers;
```

Você não esta criando uma cópia do array, só está passando a mesma referência para outra variável, então, as duas variáveis agora apontam para o mesmo array. Por isso, quando você altera o valor de `New_Numbers[0]`, está automaticamente alterando o valor de `Numbers[0]`, porque os dois arrays estão apontando para o mesmo endereço na memória.

Para fazer uma cópia do array faça assim:

```
int[] New_Numbers = Arrays.copyOf(Numbers, Numbers.length);
```

Fonte:
[problem with assigning an array to other array in java - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350249/8133067)

Comment: Já percebi. obrigado.

Comment: Diogo, a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas se alguma resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Faça também o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), para uma explicação inicial de como o site funciona.